# Parsing string to convert to Enumerated types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a web application in ASP.net and I am pulling a string of permissions from SQL for each user. How can I convert said string to an Enum?

I've tried `Enum.TryParse(value, enum.type);` This will not fit what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is my Enum:

```
private enum Permission
{
    NOTES,
    LOGS,
    SUPERUSER
};
```

here is my SQL Permission String:

`` "[[`notes`,1],[`logs`,1],[`superUser`,1]]" ``

I am wanting to associate the permission in the string, and the value to the enumerated type for each one. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the 1 the flag for enabled?

Comment: Is there a reason why each enum parameter has the same value `1`??? It will compile but all enum values will be equal (C# will use only the int value internally for comparison)!

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain why this doesn't work, what you expect to see and what actually happens. See also @MaximilianAst's comment, all your enum members have the same value.

Comment: I'm not understanding your enum, if you had to pass the int value of your enum, which value would be resolved?

Comment: Hi D Claxtion. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have one question before I post an answer.  You gave us ""[[`notes`,1],[`logs`,1],[`superUser`,1]]".  Can you explain this a little? You can't convert this string to an enum. If you had only "notes" THEN we could convert that easily to an enum of `Permission`.  Also, what is the "1" for after each permisison?

Comment: Sorry for lack of explanation, The '1' after each type is for enabled, 0 for disabled. I have them all enabled by default for testing purposes on frontend. If there is not a way to do this, I can try redo this using a Dictionary (which I didn't think of before).

Comment: @LeRoi f.y.i. C# internally only uses the integer value of an enum for comparison. But I don't know how the Enum text will be resolved (In linqpad `((Permission)1)` will resolve to `LOGS`)

Comment: Are you pulling this string directly from a single cell in your DB Table? If so, then you already have a problem.

Comment: In your enum `Permission`, you give NOTES, LOGS, and SUPERUSER all the same numeric value of 1. That's pointless.  The compiler won't know the difference and will treat them all as the same thing.

Comment: @DavidG, Yes I am. I didn't create the DB, this was given me by the previous web developer, he did it in PHP.

Comment: Putting on my "psychic" debugging hat, I'm guessing that what you want is an enum like: `private enum Permission { Notes, Log, SuperUser };`.  Then you want a `Dictionary<Permission, bool>` that you use to track which permissions are enabled and which are not.  Then, deserialize that string from JSON into that dictionary.  But, this is just a guess.  your question doesn't have enough information for me to do much more.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is match a string from your database to an enum value - can you explain why _"Enum.TryParse"_ will not do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

oK, first, I think you need to better wrap your head around what an Enum is and how they work. They can't all have the same numeric value.  So let's start here:

```
enum Permission
{
    NOTES = 1,
    LOGS = 2,
    SUPERUSER = 3
};

class PermissionValue
{
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Here, you've got a valid enum `Permission`, and then an object that holds 1) an option from `Permission` and a bool to tell us if the enum is active or not. Now, let's take a look at how to parse that (very weird) string of yours!

```
        // This is the string you get from the database:
        string dbEnumValues = "[[`notes`,1],[`logs`,1],[`superUser`,1]]";

        // We need to clean it up:
        dbEnumValues = dbEnumValues.Replace("[[", "").Replace("]]", "").Replace("],", "").Replace("`", "");

        // The line of code above will give us this: "notes,1[logs,1[superUser,1"
        // Now, we can split this into an array of strings:

        var enumValues = dbEnumValues.Split('[');

        List<PermissionValue> permissionValues = new List<PermissionValue>();

        // Next, let's loop over your array and split it further into 
        //    1) an option from Permission
        //    2) a true or false for IsActive
        foreach (var permission in enumValues)
        {
            string enumName = permission.Split(',')[0];
            string isActive = permission.Split(',')[1];
            PermissionValue permissionValue = new PermissionValue
            {
                Permission = (Permission)Enum.Parse(typeof(Permission), enumName, true),
                IsActive = isActive == "1" ? true : false
            };
            permissionValues.Add(permissionValue);
        }
```

With the code above, we end up with a `List<PermissionValue>` that looks like this:

```
Permission (enum)   IsActive
------------------------------
 NOTES               true
 LOGS                true
 SUPERUSER           true
```

Comment: You could use Enum.Parse(Type, String, Boolean) with final parameter set true to avoid the need for converting enumName to upper.

Comment: @PaulF... I'm all ears, but not following.  Can you explain further?

Comment: See [Enum.ParParse(Type, String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Enum_Parse_System_Type_System_String_System_Boolean_) - then you just need _"string enumName = permission.Split(',')[0];"_ rather than assume the enum values are upper case.

Comment: @PaulF, gotchya!  Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your Enum is working if 1 is enabled and 0 is disabled however
you can use a dictionary and with some string manipulation you can get the values from the db straight into a dictionary.

```
var perms = "[[`notes`,1],[`logs`,1],[`superUser`,1]]"; // Assuming the format is always the same...
var results = perms.Split("],")
                   .Select(x => x.Replace("`", string.Empty)
                                 .Replace("[", string.Empty)
                                 .Replace("]", string.Empty))
                   .Select(c => new KeyValuePair<Permission, bool>(Enum.Parse<Permission>(c.Split(',')[0].Trim().ToUpper()), c.Split(',')[1].Trim() == "1"))
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

EDIT:

Update the code above to use the permission Enum